# Best data type to store the values like 21.6.7.1 in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, types, data-storage

In *21.6.7.1*, *21* represents the some segment, *6* represents some lane inside that segment and so on and so forth. The individual values need to be extracted.

One way to represent this is string, any other way which is better and more convenient than string?

Comment: What language are you using?  It makes a difference as to what types are more convenient.

Comment: It is my fault I didn't mention, the language is C/C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A structure with a four fields? An array of 4 elements, can also be an option.

Comment: @dan04 thanks to both of you, the ways you specified are better than "strings" in some way or are just alternate ways?

Comment: @Anisha: integers naturally represent numbers. For comparison, for example, `"9"` compares greater than `"10"` while `9` naturally compares smaller than `10`. Therefore, if you need to manipulate the number, then using integers makes manipulation easier; if you just need to store them and serve them back, then a string might allow you not to have to convert them back and forth.

Answer (score 3):

A [bit field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) would let you store the value within a 32-bit integer.

Comment: ... assuming that the indvidual segments are small enough to fit together in one 32-bit field.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::pair<pair<int,int>,pair<int,int>>` or `tuple<int,int,int,int>`, if you don't want to have structure. Remember with both `pair` and `tuple`, there is no runtime penalty on accessing the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an array of four values: easy to compare, easy to read and to manage in future revisions of the code.